# Arch UEFI Install: Everytime machine boots a new boot option appears

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, arch-linux, uefi

I have installed Arch on a UEFI moth and just stumbled upon somehting puzzling whilst getting ready to install a dual boot windows. When going into the boot options i suddenly noticed there were 25 UEFI boot options all named the same thing (something like: KINGSTON SH103S3: Partition 1)

At first I didn't care about the issue and just went into the boot settings to delete them all, but then the settings tab in which I would normally access boot options would NOT respond to any keyboard inputs other than the arrow keys. all the other settings tabs worked just fine, but I wasn't able to change aything about the boot options. after a bit of playing around, trial and error, I noticed more boot options started appearing. Everytime I restart my machine a new boot option gets added and now even the boot menus UI has changed, from a simple terminal black and grey style, to a msdos black and blue.

[THIS](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/308305-asus-motherboard-keeps-multiplying-uefi-os-boot-options/) is all the info i could find on the issue, but appart from some gimmicky clearing of the boot options no solution was ever suggested. Also i dont have an asus moth, but:

Moth: GIGABYTE H110M-A-CF

SSD: KINGSTON SH103S3

*apologies if my wording of the question is bad, but this issue seems to far exceed my abilities, if you need anything clarified I will edit this*

Comment: Having the same issue with a Samsung SSD disk. Thanks for posting this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard of this sort of problem before. It sounds like you've got "multiplying" USB flash drive entries -- that's how I'm interpreting an entry that begins with `kingston`, since that's a common USB flash drive manufacturer. OTOH, that could be an SSD, too. Clarification of that point might be important -- but the solution or workaround is likely to be similar in either case.

I suspect that this is an entry that's being created on every boot by the firmware itself. If so, it's a bug in the firmware, so the only true solution will be to get the manufacturer to release a firmware update that fixes the bug. You might check to see if such an update is already available, and if so, to download and install it. If there's no update available, I recommend you report this as a bug to the manufacturer. Be sure to report the *exact* entry that's multiplying. Include screen shots from the firmware setup utility and/or the computer's own boot manager, as well as the output of `efibootmgr -v` (typed as `root`) in Linux.

As far as a workaround, you can use `efibootmgr` in Arch to delete unwanted entries every time you boot. You can either do this manually (which would be a pain) or write a short script to do the job and launch it as a startup script. The trick would be identifying the unwanted entries and deleting them but no others. Since you say the unwanted entries all begin with `kingston`, that's likely to be fairly easy. It's conceivable that my `refind-mkdefault` script (part of the rEFInd package) might be a useful starting point; but rather than move matching entries to the start of the boot order, you'd need to modify the script to delete matching entries -- and of course change the default matching string from `refind` to `kingston`. If you don't use rEFInd, you can grab the script itself from [the rEFInd git repository.](https://sourceforge.net/p/refind/code/ci/master/tree/refind-mkdefault) This script is written in Python, so if you're more comfortable with another scripting language, it may not be a useful starting point.

A similar problem can manifest itself because of bugs in a tool created for Fedora that's intended to fix the opposite problem of EFIs that forget boot entries. This tool can end up creating an ever-expanding list of identical boot entries. AFAIK, this problem has long been fixed, but if you've got some old Fedora boot loaders lying around, an old buggy `.efi` file might be to blame. In this case, I'd try clearing out everything from the ESP that you're not using, particularly from the `EFI/fedora` and `EFI/BOOT` directories. (As you're using Arch, I'll assume that you've got a good idea of what's on your ESP. Arch provides less in the way of automated setup tools than most distributions, so most Arch users are more familiar with such details than most users of distributions like Ubuntu or Fedora.)

One other thought occurs to me: If the entries that are multiplying are for BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode booting, rather than for EFI/UEFI-mode booting, disabling the CSM in your firmware setup utility may work around the problem.

Comment: thanks a bunch, I was worried it would be a frimware issue. I will report the problem later, but intend to buy a new Motherboard. Am I correct that this should also fix my issue? I can't seem to find any signs that there is anything wrong with my SSD or Arch installation (Its an SSD)

Comment: also yes i checked the whole boot directory to try and find double entries of some sort, nothing. no hidden nested partitions in my partition containing my EFI boot loader either....

Comment: I can't promise that a new motherboard will fix the problem (see my comments in the next-to-the-last paragraph of my answer about a Fedora program that can cause a similar problem), but it seems likely to do so. Note that boot entries are stored *in NVRAM.* Although they can *refer* to program files on the hard disk, creating new files will not normally create new NVRAM entries.